# Nuxt 3: How to add default parameters and headers to $fetch

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Trying to add any default parameters or headers (in this case a json web token as authentication header) to the $fetch composable so that i dont have to do

```
await $fetch('/api/example', {
  headers: {
    // authentication header and jwt here
  }
});
```

on every single request.
i found a way to do this by wrapping $fetch in another composable (in this case as $api) but this removed any typings on the api response, so this is not something i want to do.

Even a simplified api.ts composable like this

```
export const $api = (url: string) => {
  return $fetch(url);
}
```

does not give me the response typings from the api result that a blank $fetch in my frontend would give me.

Can i inject default values in $fetch somehow? maybe through a module/plugin/interceptor?
if not, is there a way to wrap $fetch in a composable and still keep the response typings?

i'm using nuxt3 with $fetch being ohmyfetch and i'm not using the @nuxt/auth package btw

Comment: I hope it's OK to add a question as a comment. I reckon I'm trying to do what you do. Coding an authentication with JWT token without using an auth module as it seems that Nuxt 3 provide useFetch or $fetch. But I'm at a lost, have no clue to where I should start and can't find documentation, if you could share all your current configuration (specifying files name/path as well), I'll be really grateful! Thx!

Comment: @Claire i guess you are building an SPA when you use JWT? if so, you should probably open a question and i can answer it there. its not very complicated or much code but it would get very confusing here. you can also drop a discord tag here and i can explain what you need to do there, your choice

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Nais_One ! You're totally right and I opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73398610/nuxt-3-jwt-authentication-using-fetch-and-pinia I hope I gave you every information you need, don't hesitate to ask for more on the new thread. Thanks again!
For your question I don't know if it can help but here https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/05/26/vue-3-pinia-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example a sort of fetch-wrapper is used. It's on a Vue project so not sure.

Answer (score 6):

Nuxt 3 is using [ofetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ofetch) which it exposes globally via [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) (see [here](https://github.com/nuxt/bridge/blob/ddd8eccdcba58c61cc335a64acbc99fbf446b295/packages/bridge/src/runtime/nitro-bridge.client.mjs)). If you want to use a preconfigured ofetch instance as `$fetch` instead (e.g. with headers or automatically added query params), you can override `globalThis.$fetch` in e.g. the `<script>` of your `app.vue` using `ofetch.create` and providing your default options (as documented [in this section](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch#%EF%B8%8F-create-fetch-with-default-options) of the ofetch documentation). You can find all available options you can pass to `ofetch.create` in the [ofetch code here](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch/blob/ff697d7b4a43c4399897b69097485b3785dfd661/src/fetch.ts#L26) and [here](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch/blob/ff697d7b4a43c4399897b69097485b3785dfd661/src/fetch.ts#L7).

### Example code

**app.vue**

```js
<script setup>
import { ofetch } from 'ofetch'

globalThis.$fetch = ofetch.create({ baseUrl: '', onRequest: () => {}, ... })
</script>
```

Comment: Your solution works, but it is not suitable for authentication because headers are set on the Nuxt server for $fetch. 
That is, about the initialisation of the application for each user, the header will be changed on the server, which will be common to all. 

Therefore, in the context of this question, the answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a composable containing a wrapper around `$fetch` for example under `/composables/api.ts` you can have:

```
export function $api<T>(
  request: Parameters<typeof $fetch<T>>[0],
  opts?: Parameters<typeof $fetch<T>>[1],
) {
  const auth = useAuth()

  return $fetch<T>(request, {
    ...opts,
    headers: {
      Authorization: auth.logged ? `Bearer ${auth.accessToken}` : '',
      ...opts?.headers,
    },
  })
}
```

Here `useAuth()` is a Pinia store containing auth information like logged and the access token.

Like this you can simply use `$api()` anywhere in the app.

Comment: Just perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've made some small changes to the answer of Riad Hachemane, because I saw that not all types were being copied to the wrapper function correctly.

```js
import type { NitroFetchOptions, NitroFetchRequest } from 'nitropack'

const $api = async <
    DefaultT = unknown,
    DefaultR extends NitroFetchRequest = NitroFetchRequest,
    T = DefaultT,
    R extends NitroFetchRequest = DefaultR,
    O extends NitroFetchOptions<R> = NitroFetchOptions<R>
  >(
    url: R,
    options?: O
  ) => $fetch<T>(url, {
    ...options,
    headers: {
      Authorization: auth.logged ? `Bearer ${auth.accessToken}` : '',
      ...options?.headers
    }
  })
```